# How to function with ajax calls asynchronously and display loader until done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, loader

how can I call ajax request or any function simple in new thread?

I know about `async: false` but my code has this structure:

1.user click on some item, and this fire click event
2.in event I call this function

```
var myData= {};
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "...",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (s0) {
            myData.s0= s0;


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sss",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (s1) {
                    myData.s1 = s1;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "...",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (s2) {
                            myData.s2= s2;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // I need call this function when all ajax are done.
    myFunc(myData);
```

My current code works but causes the web freezes until data are not downloaded beaouse I have `asyn: false` but I do not know how to solve it asynchronously

Optimal solution for me is call this freezing and display loading gif until done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no fix for UI freeze during a synchronous AJAX so you might want to try web workers but it has its own caveat .I would suggest you to use jquery promise so that you don't need to define separate success ,error callbacks .A promise is **guaranteed** to yield  so at the end of chain either you will have values in myData or not but it won't hangup forever

```
//show loader
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "...",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
}).then(function( s0, textStatus, jqXHR ){ 
         myData.s0= s0;
         return  $.ajax( {
         type: "GET",
         url: "sss",
         async: false,
         cache: false,
         dataType: "json"} );
 }).then(function( s1, textStatus, jqXHR ) { 
          myData.s1 = s1;
          $.ajax( {
          type: "GET",
          url: "...",
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          dataType: "json"});  
}).then(function( s2, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
          myData.s2= s2;
          //hide loader
})
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `async:false` to `async:true` on all ajax calls, show loading gif at the start of your function where you initialize `myData` and call the function you want to call when all data is loaded in the success function on the last ajax call (just after `myData.s2 = s2`)